# Python & Unittest open second browser, after first test have completed and test fails

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-unittest, test-suite, multiple-browsers

Found many topics about this problem, but didn't find any easy described problem solving, so creating new topic with this problem and maybe will get much better answer to this problem.

I have created test case for **LoginTest** and test case for **LegalPersonSearchTest**. Both these test cases are in separate files *login.py* and *legalPersonSearch.py*

```
from utils.utils import *
from selenium import webdriver
from locators.locators import Locators
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import unittest
from pages.loginPage import LoginPage


class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):

@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    cls.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    cls.driver.maximize_window()
    cls.driver.get(URL)

def test_valid_login(self):
    driver = self.driver

    login = LoginPage(driver)
    login.fill_login_form(adminUsername, adminPassword)
    login.click_login_button()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I think the reason why new browser opens between tests, is declaring *driver* in second file.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
from pages.legalPersonSearchPage import LegalPersonSearchPage

class LegalPersonSearchTest(unittest.TestCase):

@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

def test_valid_organization_search(self):
    driver = self.driver
    legal = LegalPersonSearchPage(driver)

    legal.open_legal_person_search_page()

@classmethod
def tearDown(cls):
    cls.driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

How to modify **LoginTest** that browser open only one time, instead between tests?

I need to modify it, because after login (which is 1/2 of test) comes second part of test. It will complete and then browser closes and open new and start again with login.

As someone told me, then best practice is to keep login test part out of whole test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer one of your questions -- `driver` gets opened twice because you have two different `setUp()` methods, one for each of your classes - `LoginTest` and `LegalPersonSearchTest`. When you run `test_valid_login`, your `setUpClass()` method gets called, which initializes the `driver`. Then, test runs. This `driver` instance never gets torn down, so window remains open.

Then, `test_valid_organization_search` runs. This class ALSO has its own `setUpClass()` method, which initializes another `driver` instance. So now you have two drivers, both of which are opened in the `setUpClass()` method of each class file.

This set up is producing results that you have not intended. I think you are slightly misunderstanding what "*best practice is to keep login test part out of whole test*" means here.

This does not mean you need to write **two separate** tests -- one that logs in, and one that tests the rest of the functionality. This is actually [bad practice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/335407/is-it-bad-practice-for-unit-tests-to-be-dependent-on-each-other), because you want your test cases to run independently of one another -- test cases should not rely on previous test cases to execute properly.

I think the solution you are looking for here is to write the login functionality into your `setUp()` method so that login is always performed before a test case starts.

This approach will prevent you from having the login part in with the test -- that's the original goal you mentioned here.

You can adjust your classes by removing the duplicate `setUp()` method, and inheriting `LoginTest` into your `LegalPersonSearchTest` so that you are only setting up once:

```
from utils.utils import *
from selenium import webdriver
from locators.locators import Locators
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import unittest
from pages.loginPage import LoginPage

# this is our "base" class
class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):

driver = None # driver instance that we will inherit into LegalPersonSearchTest

# initialize driver, go to testing URL, etc.
def setUp(cls):
    cls.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    cls.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    cls.driver.maximize_window()
    cls.driver.get(URL)

    # call login here to login before test
    login_page = LoginPage(cls.driver)
    login_page .fill_login_form(adminUsername, adminPassword)
    login_page .click_login_button()

# move teardown into same class as setUp()
def tearDown(cls):
    cls.driver.quit()
```

We have declared a class variable for `driver` that you can pass into `LegalPersonSearchTest`. We have also removed the `__main__` call, because the only entry point we need is the `test_` method in `LegalPersonSearchTest`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
from pages.legalPersonSearchPage import LegalPersonSearchPage
from login_test import LoginTest # unsure of file name containing LoginTest class

class LegalPersonSearchTest(LoginTest): # inherit LoginTest here so we can use driver


def test_valid_organization_search(self):

    legal_page = LegalPersonSearchPage(self.driver)
    legal_page .open_legal_person_search_page()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

We have changed a few things here:

- Entry point for main method designated by `__main__` -- we only need this in one place, on the test case level (`LegalPersonSearchTest`)
- Removed duplicate `setUp()` method calls that were resulting in multiple driver instances getting created (mentioned in your problem description)
- Created single class instance of driver in `LoginTest` class to be passed into `LegalPersonSearchTest` class
- Modified `setUp()` method on `LoginTest` to initialize the driver and login -- so that you do not have to include login code for any test!

Update: Changes made following comments:

- Removed `login` method from `LoginTest` class and moved login code under `setUp()` -- this will get performed before every test case now
- Modified `test_valid_organization_search` to use `self.driver` instead of `driver` when initializing PageObject

I've made many of these changes based on [this sample Python test architecture](https://github.com/harbourc/Generic_Python_UI_Auto) that I pushed to my GitHub. The files I used as templates were `base_test_fixture.py` (for your `LoginTest`), and `test_web_driver.py` for your `LegalPersonSearchTest`.

You may notice that `base_test_fixture.py` also contains `def _testInitialize()` and `def _testCleanup()` -- these are methods that you can **override** in your `LegalPersonSearchTest` class to perform **additional** steps to be run before your `test_` method. The idea here is that if you have multiple `.py` files containing test cases, but each `.py` file requires slightly different setup, and you need to do more than just `setUp()` method calls for. You can override the `testInitialize()` and `testCleanup()` methods in the test case class, and these methods will execute **after** `setUp()` and **before** the actual `test_` method.

Let me know if you have any questions about this -- it's quite a bit to explain, but once you learn this architecture, you have a very powerful way of organizing and executing your test cases.

Comment: Love it your whole answer, how you described changes and why should change. Very nice. I thought about this also, but didn't really understand how to perform it. Made changes like you wrote plus there were missed that need to import that class in `LegalPersonSearchTest` file to get access to `LoginTest`. But there is problem with `login(cls)`. It is called before it is declared. In PyCharm I can see that it already show that there is problem. Tried to run to approve that is will get error and it gets `line 31, in setUp login(cls) --> NameError: name 'login' is not defined`

Comment: My apologies, I did write this without being able to test first — the idea is there, but I do need to make a few corrections for this sample to be fully working. Once I can get somewhere that I can test this out, I will tag you and update my answer!

Comment: @MārisL I've updated my code sample and included a link to my GitHub repo which I have been using as a "template"  to apply to your problem -- I thought it may be helpful for your to see where I am getting this information from.

Comment: This is fantastic. I was struggling with this problem for two days and it now works. After LoginTest completes there is 10 seconds delay when starts LegalPersonSearchTest but about this I will try to Google and find why it is like that. Biggest thanks again and hope someone, who have problem like this, will use your solution.